# Admin Search Report Data

Tags: search

On the /admin/reports/search report, there are the most searched terms listed. On the installation I'm responsible for since a few weeks, this list is emptied every day. This is one part of the problem, but my question is another, as I also have to create a detailed report on how the search was being used.

For that reason I'd like to export the data as it is shown on the /admin/reports/search page on a daily basis. Unfortunately the content of the database table "search_total" seems not to be the resource of the report. I looked into the Drupal Search Tables: https://www.drupal.org/node/2360879 but didn't manage to reproduce the contents of the report page.

Does anyone know how this data is curated and how I can export this data via mysql?

I'm using the default drupal search and Drupal v9.5.11.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the codebase shows that this route is provided in `core/modules/dblog/dblog.routing.yml`. The route is controlled by `\Drupal\dblog\Controller\DbLogController::topLogMessages` with type `search`. So the complete query is:

```php
    $header = [
      ['data' => $this->t('Count'), 'field' => 'count', 'sort' => 'desc'],
      ['data' => $this->t('Message'), 'field' => 'message'],
    ];
    $count_query = $this->database->select('watchdog');
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(DISTINCT([message]))');
    $count_query->condition('type', $type);

    $query = $this->database->select('watchdog', 'w')
      ->extend(PagerSelectExtender::class)
      ->extend(TableSortExtender::class);
    $query->addExpression('COUNT([wid])', 'count');
    $query = $query
      ->fields('w', ['message', 'variables'])
      ->condition('w.type', $type)
      ->groupBy('message')
      ->groupBy('variables')
      ->limit(30)
      ->orderByHeader($header);
    $query->setCountQuery($count_query);
    $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The code can be translated to this sql statement:
SELECT 
  COUNT(w.wid) AS count, 
  w.message, 
  w.variables
FROM 
  watchdog w
WHERE 
  w.type = 'search'
GROUP BY 
  w.message, 
  w.variables
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(w.wid) DESC,
  w.message ASC
;